# Typed google test, combine types, c++

Tags: c++, templates, types, googletest, generate

I am using [google test](https://github.com/google/googletest) for testing my c++ lib that does pixel conversions and other things.

Now consider I have these models participating in the test.

```
using Models = testing::Types<ARGBNormalized, RGBNormalized, HSLNormalized,
                              HSVNormalized, YUVNormalized, YCCNormalized>;
```

When I need to test conversion I need **two distinct** models from these types.

So I create a struct like this.

```
template<typename Source, typename Dest>
struct ConversionTypes{
  using SourceModelType = Source;
  using DestModelType = Dest;
};
```

And then just add this.

```
using ConversionModels = testing::Types<ConversionTypes<ARGBNormalized,YCCNormalized>.....>;
```

If model's count were say `n` I would have to write `n*(n-1)` types in conversion models list. It does not matter if I had like 4 or 3 color models, but I am gonna have 10+ models in my program, and it is insane to write 90 combinations by-hand.
So is there a way tp somehow generate these `ConversionModels` from `Models` I already wrote?

Answer (score 1):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html), all it takes is a little extra predicate. We can write the transformation as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <boost/mp11/algorithm.hpp>

template<typename Source, typename Dest>
struct ConversionTypes {
  using SourceModelType = Source;
  using DestModelType = Dest;
};

template<typename>   struct SameConversionTypes : std::false_type{};
template<typename T> struct SameConversionTypes<ConversionTypes<T, T>> : std::true_type{};

using Models = ::testing::Types<char, int, long, long long>;

using ConversionModels = 
        boost::mp11::mp_remove_if<
            boost::mp11::mp_product<ConversionTypes, Models, Models>,
            SameConversionTypes
        >;
```

`mp_product` applies `ConversionTypes` to the Cartesian product of the list `Models` with itself. The result is produced in the same sort of list as `Models`. So we obtain a `::testing::Types<ConversionTypes<...>...>`. However, since you do not want to test the identity conversion, we use `mp_remove_if` to get rid of all elements of the form `ConversionTypes<T, T>` (which is what we defined the helper predicate `SameConversionTypes` for).

---

Having said that, while this works with the GoogleTest trunk, the above may fail for you. That is because google test only switched to using variadic templates for `Types` only in the last 18 months or so. Prior it generated a `testing::Types` template that took a very large number of arguments (to simulate variadic templates for older compilers). If you use a slightly older version of GoogleTest, then you can still rely on `boost::mp11` to get by, with a little alteration.

```
using Models_ = boost::mp11::mp_list<char, int, long, long long>;
using Models  = boost::mp11::mp_rename<Models_, ::testing::Types>;

using ConversionModels = 
    boost::mp11::mp_rename<
        boost::mp11::mp_remove_if<
            boost::mp11::mp_product<ConversionTypes, Models_, Models_>,
            SameConversionTypes
        >,
        ::testing::Types
    >;
```

`mp_list` is a truly variadic type list. So we can define everything in terms of it, and then use `mp_rename` to replace the "outer shell". It turns `mp_list<A, ..., Z>` into `::testing::Types<A, ..., Z>`.

Only caveat remaining is to be mindful of GTest's implementation limits. It may not support a type list that is 90 types long. You may need to regenerate the header locally to increase how many types it can support.

Comment: unfortunately I don't use boost